# Secure login with flutter

Tags: sql, flutter, security

I have a couple of scenarios I would like to play with and was wondering if anyone can help me.

I have a flutter app that relies on external data. It's not very sensitive data but if my project goes forward, it will have some company privileged info.

For testing purposes, I have a Google sheet as a database. I could have all people sign up for a Gmail account and then grant permissions to access that sheet.

What happens if my boss likes the idea though? We have a sql database that requires you to be attached to the local network or VPNed to it.

How can I securely pull data from that database without needlessly exposing us or revoke permissions if a user gets fired? Would everyone need their own login to the dB?

Comment: Don't use an SQL database directly in an app. The common way that is very similar to your "Google Sheet" approach is using [Google Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs). It allows to create user accounts to create "user compartments" or use it as "public database" where everybody has access to.

Comment: The issue is the database already exists. Trying to bring a mobile app to an existing platform.

Comment: Then you should write a server application that exposes this "database" e.g. as REST service to the app. Then you can later migrate the Google sheet system to a real database without having to change the app. Using Google sheet als backend Database is a high business risk, tell that your boss.